# PointFree programming

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I want to know if it is possible to convert a recursive function into point free definition.

If we take an easy recursive function.

```
factorial :: int-> int
factorial 0=1
factorial n+1= (n+1) *factorial n
```

IF we have non recursive def.

```
factorial :: int-> int
factorial n= product [1..n]  
   <=> factorial n = product.enumFromTo 1 n 
   <=> factorial   = product.enumFromTo 1
```

But how can i do the same on the recursive definition?

Reason why i am asking is that i want to make `transformationsApply` pointfree.

```
transformationsApply :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [([a], [a])] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
transformationsApply _ _ [] _= Nothing
transformationsApply wc func ((a,b):xs) (y:ys)
   = orElse (transformationApply wc func (y:ys) (a,b)) 
            (transformationsApply wc func xs (y:ys))
```

`transformationApply` used above is defined as

```
transformationApply :: Eq a => a -> (([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> (([a], [a]) -> Maybe [a])))

transformationApply wc func xs (a,b) 
   = mmap ((substitute wc b).func) (match wc a xs)
```

Comment: Its better to keep your code readable than to write some complex pointfree form.

Comment: what (type) is `orelse`? `substitute`? `mmap`? `match`?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to keep your code more readable than to try converting it to incomprehensible pointfree form.

The easiest way to convert a function to pointfree form is to ask lambdabot. Now when you have recursive function you can convert that to non-recursive using fix. Here is the example of `fact` function (A direct conversion from what lambdabot gave) and you can see how readable it is.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Function


if' :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
if' True  x _ = x
if' False _ y = y

fact = fix $ ap (flip if' 1 . (0 ==)) . ap (*) . (. subtract 1)
```

Comment: Or `cabal install pointfree` and use `pointfree` directly. I don’t find the converted version so unpleasant in this case. `flip if' 1` sets the `then` case, `(0 ==)` is the (partially applied) condition, `(. subtract 1)` is selecting the second argument and subtracting one from it, and `ap (*)` is recurring with the first argument and combining the results with `(*)`.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yes, But I am not sure how you convert pattern matching to pointfree. This will require an additional `Eq` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* convert most recursive functions to point free form in an automatic manner, the result is likely to be ugly and rather useless, as others have shown.

However what you have here is not really a general recursion.  You have a *fold* on a list, building up a result from applying a function to each list element and then combining them.

Haskell has building blocks for folding and otherwise recursing on lists specifically, which will give a much prettier result.  (Although you still need to use your judgement of whether it is an improvement.)  The most common such building blocks are the functions `foldr` and `map`.  In fact your example can be rewritten as:

```
transformationsApply :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [([a], [a])] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
transformationsApply wc func xs (y:ys) =
    foldr orElse Nothing (map (transformationApply wc func (y:ys)) xs)
transformationsApply _ _ [] [] = Nothing
```

(The last line is because of a corner case: your original function checks if the last argument is empty in all cases *except* when the xs list is.  Maybe you don't need this.)

Answer (score 1):

starting with `factorial`, first we'll need a type case discriminator, to encapsulate the pattern matching on numbers for us,

```
num :: (Num a) => b -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
num z _  0 = z
num _ nz x = nz x
```

now, using the identity `(g =<< f) x = g (f x) x`, we write

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Function (fix)

fact :: (Num c, Enum c) => c -> c
fact = num 1 ((*) =<< (fact.pred))
```

To get the truly pointfree form of it we need to push `fact` to the right, and `fix` it:

```
     = num 1 . ((*) =<<) . (.pred) $ fact
     = fix (num 1 . ((*) =<<) . (.pred))
```

---

proceeding to your 2nd function, as [Ørjan Johansen points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19900636/849891) it is essentially a right fold (if we ignore the intricacies of the forcing order for arguments, as determined by the explicit patterns that you use):

```
transformationsApply :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [([a], [a])] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
transformationsApply a b c d
   = foldr (orElse . transformationApply a b d) Nothing c
```

which already looks quite [*combinatory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Combinatory_logic). So here *recursion* is encapsulated by *`foldr`*, instead of being explicitly expressed by *`fix`*.

We could juggle some more for the arguments order, but that's much less fun:

```
   = flip (foldr . (orElse .) . transformationApply a b) Nothing d c
   = flip (flip (foldr . (orElse .) . transformationApply a b) Nothing) c d
   = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll need an inline branching operation, while

```
if' True  t _ = t
if' False _ e = e
```

is popular another form is more useful. I'll call it `p`

```
p check a | check a   = Right a
          | otherwise = Left  a
```

which is powerful enough to define `if'`

```
if' b t e = either (const e) (const t) . p (const b)
```

but has the nicer property

```
(\a -> if' (check a) (t a) (e a)) == either e t . p check
```

and it lets us get rid of the first branch in `factorial`

```
factorial' = either (const 1) (\n -> n * factorial (n-1)) . p (==0)
```

which means we just need to somehow eliminate the `(\n -> n * factorial (n-1))` bit. Using the `(&&&)` "fanout" combinator from `Control.Arrow`

```
(&&&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (a -> (b, c))
```

we have

```
(\n -> n * factorial (n-1)) == uncurry (*) . (id &&& factorial . (+ negate 1))
```

which is a bit annoying due to `(-)` sectioning ambiguity. I'll leave it for now, though so that our final function is

```
factorial'' :: Int -> Int
factorial'' = 
  either (const 1) 
         (uncurry (*) 
          . (id &&& factorial'' . (+ negate 1))) 
  . p (==0)
```

and the recursive part of the definition works just fine. Technically the type is more general than that

```
factorial'' :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a
```

which is perhaps a little unsatisfying since we need the `Eq` constraint now while the pattern-matching version does not. We could do better if our numbers had natural destructors available to us. For instance, if we define our own naturals with "natural" constructors and destructors

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

cons :: Maybe Nat -> Nat
cons Nothing  = Z
cons (Just n) = S n

uncons :: Nat -> Maybe Nat
uncons Z     = Nothing
uncons (S n) = Just n
```

We can do all the rest without further pattern matching. Let's get a `plus` and a `mult`

```
--  Z   + n = n
--  S m + n = S (m + n)    
plus n = maybe n (S . plus n) . uncons

--  Z   * n = Z
--  S m * n = n + (m * n)
mult n = maybe Z (plus n . mult n) . uncons
```

And with these we have

```
naturalFact :: Nat -> Nat
naturalFact = maybe (S Z) (uncurry mult . (S &&& naturalFact)) . uncons
```

which is pretty satisfying. It's probably as satisfying as you can get without eliminating the recursive step and entering the Squiggol style of pointfree programming entirely or Church-encoding all of our pattern matches away entirely.